# For my jupyter notebook in the dato-env key words are not highlighted and code does not seem to run. Given the errors I see, why is that?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter, graphlab

Below are the errors I get on the terminal which the Dato Launcher starts. 
The Jupyter notebook does come up, but keywords are not highlighted and execute cell does not seem to do anything (for e.g. a print won't actually print anything).

```
[E 13:03:15.259 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception, closing connection.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/xyz/anaconda/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 407, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/xyz/anaconda/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/xyz/anaconda/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 147, in _handle_kernel_info_reply
        self._finish_kernel_info(info)
      File "/Users/xyz/anaconda/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 162, in _finish_kernel_info
        self.session.adapt_version = int(protocol_version.split('.')[0])
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix this, you need to update a package in the dato-env. After switching to that environment (using source activate data-env) do:

```
conda update pyzmq
```

If that works, good. If you get the error shown below then read on.

From dato-env you need to unistall conda-build and conda-env (and any other conda* packages -- I only saw the two I listed).

First switch to the dato-env

```
source activate dato-env
```

Then:

```
conda uninstall conda-env
conda uninstall conda-build
```

Relaunch jupyter use the dato launcher.

Note, when I installed graphlab, conda-build and conda-env were present in dato-env. Apparently, they should only be present in the root environment.

If you get an error like this when installing or updating any packages in a non-root environment:

```
Error: 'conda' can only be installed into the root environment
```

It's probably because you have a conda* package in the non-root environment. The solution is to uninstall the packages as I showed above.

How does a conda* package get into the non-root environment? I think this can happen if you use the clone root command. If you google the above error message you can get more details.